# How to avoid recalculation in shiny R each time a tab is clicked on?

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny application, I have noticed that when I have multiple tabs, each time I click on the tab, the output is recalculated. I wasn't expecting this behavior since no inputs were changed. How can I keep it so that it only recalculates once an actual input is changed?

Comment: Could you provide example code which illustrates the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your calculataions prior and save them to `name.rda` file with `save` function, and then add a line `load("name.rda")` at the beggining of the `server.r` file - the data will be loaded only at the beggining of your application. Can't help much without your code.